# Video stops after use voice input on iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm developing a live social app, it's able users have text chat when they are watching gameplay.

I found AVPlayer will stop video when user tap voice input on the keyboard.

How do I fixed this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will happen because when you record your voice, the sound coming from the video will interrupt the recording (voice coming out of the phone speaker will heavily distort sound going through the microphone) Thus the video will automatically be stopped.

Please try adding the code below: (only need to set it once)

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCa‌​tegoryAmbient, error: nil) 
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

Comment: but neither AVPlayer or AVPlayerItem wont change their status, It's confused.

Comment: btw, I found Facebook iOS won't pause their video when user using voice input, but I can't tell they are using AVPlayer or not.

Comment: try this: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

Comment: You only need to set these once not everytime. Please try and come back to me

Comment: it's only ok in simulator

Answer (score -1):

my solution is add observer of

> UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange

I have no idea how to playing video and using voice input at the same time ( just like facebook iOS behavior )

however I can resume the video after voice input is done ( just like youtube iOS behavior )

```
func textInputMethodDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    print("textInputMethodDidChange")

    if self.textInputMode == nil || self.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage != "dictation" {

        self.player.play()

    }

}
```